# Пунктуация при наличии однородных членов предложения и деепричастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот, и

Пример: "Он посмотрел на меня с любовью и нежностью(,) и(,) мягко улыбнувшись, помахал мне рукой. Где должна быть запятая после однородных членов предложения ("любовью и нежностью") и перед деепричастным оборотом ("мягко улыбнувшись")? Хочется поставить запятую после после "нежностью" из-за повторяющегося союза "и". Но как будет правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Разную работу выполняют здесь союзы "и".

Посмотрел так и сяк **и** помахал.

*Он посмотрел на меня с любовью и нежностью и, мягко улыбнувшись, помахал мне рукой.*

Только деепричастный оборот обособляем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[источник](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/v-kakih-sluchayah-pered-soyuzom-i-stavitsya-zapyataya.html)**